# Query XML column using another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have a SQL table `Products` with 2 columns as below.

| ID | ProductDetails |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | `<XML>` |
| 3 | `<XML>` |

The XML column holds the following data:

```
<Products>
    <product key="0" description="">Product1</product>
    <product key="1" description="">Product2</product>
    <product key="2" description="">Product3</product>
    <product key="3" description="">Product4</product>
    <product key="4" description="">Product5</product>
    <product key="5" description="">Product6</product>
    <product key="6" description="">Product7</product>
    <product key="7" description="">Product8</product>
</Products>
```

How can I get the relevant node from the `ProductDetails` for `ProductTitle`?

For example: if the `ID` column has 3, I need to query the `ProductDetails` column and create a new column with just the `ProductTitle` to be `Product3`.

| ID | ProductDetails | ProductTitle |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | `<XML>` | Product5 |
| 3 | `<XML>` | Product3 |

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Love to see what you have tried.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, ProductDetails XML);
INSERT @tbl (ID, ProductDetails) VALUES
(3, N'<Products>
  <product key="0" description="">Product1</product>
  <product key="1" description="">Product2</product>
  <product key="2" description="">Product3</product>
  <product key="3" description="">Product4</product>
  <product key="4" description="">Product5</product>
  <product key="5" description="">Product6</product>
  <product key="6" description="">Product7</product>
  <product key="7" description="">Product8</product>
</Products>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID 
    , ProductDetails.value('(/Products/product[@key=sql:column("ID")]/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS ProductTitle
FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

| ID | ProductTitle |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | Product4 |

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the XML `.nodes()` function to access and filter the "product" XML elements, and then the `.value()` function to extract the desired text value from that node. Both take xpath parameters to specify the data to be extracted.

Try

```
SELECT P.*, X.N.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM @Products P
CROSS APPLY @ProductXml.nodes('/Products/product[@key=sql:column("P.ID")]') X(N)
```

or equivilently:

```
SELECT P.*, PN.ProductName
FROM @Products P
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT ProductName = X.N.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
    FROM @ProductXml.nodes('/Products/product[@key=sql:column("P.ID")]') X(N)
) PN
```

or even

```
SELECT P.*, PN.ProductName
FROM @Products P
JOIN (
    SELECT
        ProductKey = X.N.value('@key', 'nvarchar(max)'),
        ProductName = X.N.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
    FROM @ProductXml.nodes('/Products/product') X(N)
) PN ON PN.ProductKey = P.ID
```

The subselect in the latter could also be used to build a temp table for more traditional query access.

In the xpath strings,

- `/Products/product` selects all product nodes
- `[@key = ...]` selects the `key` attribute to be used as a filter
  (equality)
- `sql:column("P.ID")` allows a reference back to a column
  in the containing SQL
- `text()` is a special selector that chooses the text within the XML element
- `[1]` filters that down to at most a single value (a singleton)
- `nvarchar(max)` defines the result datatype for the `.value()` function.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bUQ6G8KV).